# Magento eCheque auto update order to processing

Tags: magento, paypal-ipn

There was an order that was paid with PayPal echeque. I check it on admin dashboard, the history of status had the following:

```
29/04/2014 8:10:31 AM|Processing
Customer Notification Not Applicable
IPN "Completed". Registered notification about captured amount of $71.60. Transaction ID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".

23/04/2014 4:10:12 AM|Payment Review
Customer Not Notified
IPN "Pending". The payment eCheck is not yet cleared. There is no update for the payment. Transaction ID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".

23/04/2014 4:09:57 AM|Payment Review
Customer Notification Not Applicable
IPN "Pending". Capturing amount of $71.60 is pending approval on gateway. Transaction ID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".

23/04/2014 4:07:43 AM|Pending Payment
Customer Not Notified
```

Will PayPal auto-update the status of Magneto orders? I know that order which was payed with echeque always need be updated manually.

Comment: Are you using Paypal module that is comming with magento?

Comment: yes, paypal module built-in magento

Comment: Can you check this method returnUrlAction in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php maybe it will help you understand what is going on when you are returning back from PayPal to Magento